# How to detect which gradle project that contains classes that have dependency on an updated class?

Tags: java, gradle, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

For example if I have class A1 in project A, B1 in project B, C1 in project C, and D1 in project D. Both class A1 and C1 have dependency on class D1. When I updated class D1 I want to track which projects contains A1 and C1. The objective is that I want to only build project A, C, and D on my CI.

PS: I use monorepo

Comment: How are the projects separated? In theory if each project is a separate module with separate gradle file, you would have dependencies section where it's defined project A and C depend on D. It wouldn't be a strict checking if specific D class has changed then re-run build of A and C, but I think it's better and cleaner that way

Comment: Yes they are separate projects with separate gradle file. There is already checking on whether any updates on project D. 

Maybe I have restate the problem. This project D is actually some kind of a library, so although class A and C have a dependency on the project it might be from different class/module. When the class which project A have dependency on have an update, I want my CI to only build project A and D despite project C also have a dependency on project D. I hope my explanation clear enough.

Comment: I might be missing something, when you're building gradle project with modules, it detects automatically and rebuilds only what it needs, otherwise uses cache, unless you've disabled cache. In other words, should be working that way already